# Scope Error in Javascript. Calling a method within a different method of that object

Tags: javascript, scope, prototypejs, this

I've got a variable timekeep.

```
var timeKeep;
```

and I define it thusly:

```
timeKeep = Class.create({
  initialize: function() {
    this.initObservers();
  },

  initObservers: function() {
    $$('input').each( function(el) {
      el.observe('keypress', function(ev) {
        // the key code for 'enter/return' is 13
        if(ev.keyCode === 13){
          timeKeep.submit();
              // Uncaught TypeError: Object function klass() {
              // this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
              // } has no method 'submit'
        }
      });
    });
  },

  submit: function() {
    alert('Submitted!');
  }
})
```

The error I am getting is commented out below the line that it occurs. It's got something to do with calling a timeKeep method within a different scope I think?

Is there a problem calling timeKeep.method() inside a foreach statement?

Comment: you are missing a `});` for your `each` function

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I rewrote the code for this post, must've missed it. Fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with you OOP style. Use a closure so you call the current instance of your *class*.

```
  initObservers: function () {
      var that = this;
      $$('input')
          .each(function (el) {
              el.observe('keypress', function (ev) {
                  // the key code for 'enter/return' is 13
                  if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
                      that.submit();
                  }
              });
          });
  },
```

You could also look at [bind](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/bind/)

```
  initObservers: function() {
      var submit = this.submit.bind(this);
      $$('input')
          .each(function (el) {
              el.observe('keypress', function (ev) {
                  // the key code for 'enter/return' is 13
                  if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
                      submit();
                  }
              });
          });
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. I used the binding solution. I am getting similar errors in other parts of my code too, though. In a different function, I called a method this.isValidRow(), but get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isValidRow'". I call this.isValidRow() in the first line of that method, so I don't know why it wouldnt recognize it. Does this sound like a related problem?

Comment: Probably, if it `this` is in a different scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that `Class.create` returns an instance of an object of the type you are defining, but no, it returns a constructor function for creating instances of the class you are defining.

You can add the new keyword to the assignment and then you will have in timeKeep what you want to:

```
timeKeep = new Class.create({
...
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested - using `Function#bind()` will solve your problem but there is a cleaner way so that you can continue to use `this` inside the class scope.

Also look into the `invoke()` method as this is a perfect opportunity to use it. `$$()` returns a list of elements and if you want to perform the same function on all of the elements `invoke()` will handle iterating over the list.

```
timeKeep = Class.create({
  initialize: function() {
    this.initObservers();
  },

  initObservers: function() {
    $$('input').invoke('observe','keypress',function(ev) {
      // the key code for 'enter/return' is 13
      if(ev.keyCode === 13){
        timeKeep.submit();
        // Uncaught TypeError: Object function klass() {
        // this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // } has no method 'submit'
      }
//Add the bind method to the closure to bind 'this' inside that function scope
//to 'this' of the class
//the binding will allow you to call this.submit() instead of timeKeep.submit
//as well as access any of the class properties and methods inside this closure
    }.bind(this));
  } ,

  submit: function() {
    alert('Submitted!');
  }
});
```

PrototypeJS documentation on observers http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/ - look at the heading **Using an Instance Method as a Handler**